# getAllFonts() returns different names on different machines

Tags: java, swing, fonts

I am writing this program that uses custom fonts that I register in the GraphicsEnvironment. The issue is that the font names are returned differently on different machines, one is a mac OS and the other is a linux.

```
public void loadCustomFonts() {
    LOG.info("Loading custom fonts.");
    File folder = new File("fontsDirectory");
    GraphicsEnvironment ge = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
    Arrays.stream(folder.listFiles()).forEach(f -> {
        try {
            ge.registerFont(Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, f));
        } catch (FontFormatException e) {
            LOG.error(e);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            LOG.error(e);
        }
    });
}
```

However when I run the following code, I get different outputs on different machines:

```
Arrays.stream(ge.getAllFonts()).forEach(f -> System.out.println(f.getName()));
```

For example, on one machine, the font name will be displayed as FontLight, and on another it will be displayed as Font Light (with space in between).

Any explanation of why I am getting this behavior?

Comment: `getName` will give the logical name of the font, and this logical name could be derived in some way? Did you tried `getFontName`/`getFamily`?

Comment: Tried it, still different outputs.

Comment: TTF can have different names PostScript name and Full name. PostScript names are space-free; it may then be possible that on Linux java uses **PostScript name** while OSX uses **Full name**. Is that it? For example on my OSX I was able to see (through Font Book app) that Arial Hebrew has PostScript name `ArialHebrew` and full name `Arial Hebrew`.

Comment: Can you be precise in what you mean with "different machines"? Are we talking the same OS, different OS, the same JRE/JDK version, different versions, etc? Those details are crucial to answer your question.

Answer (score 2):

Modern font formats are complex and have a long history. For backwards-compatibility reasons, when a new better way to declare font metadata is defined, it's added on top of the previous ones that sediment and are still present in font files. OpenType has at least  three such layers right now IIRC.

The oldest ones have all kinds of restrictions and are intended to be backwards-compatible with older formats such as Postscript fonts (no spaces in family names, only 4 possible faces normal/bold/italic/bold italic, 7bit ASCII only), there is another with absolutely no restriction on naming, and a newer one with sanity rules added back (some font authors were putting human text in the face names, that didn't really work for CSS selectors like bolder). And probably others I forgot about (OS/2 and Panose info anyone?).

Text stacks read the most recent layer that existed when they were written, so depending on their age they don't read the same one in the same files. It is usually expected of the font author to declare consistent information in the various metadata layers, but, technically, nothing stops the author from stating the font is named "Foo" in one layer and "Bar" in another (awful stuff happens when the font author uses a font authoring app that puts placeholder info in the metadata, or when the font is created by copying another one, and the author does not check properly he changed all the metadata layers before releasing). Plus, even when the author strives to be consistent, the technical restrictions associated with the different layers do not permit using strictly identical values in some cases.

Also modern operating systems try to fix fonts with broken metadata, so even when two bits of software read the same metadata layer it can be altered by the system text stack before getting to the app.

As Java is getting better integrated in various operating systems it tends to rely more on the system text stack, as users tend to hate when Java does not refer to a font file the same way as the rest of the system. Recent openjdks access Linux fonts through fontconfig for example and fontconfig has very complex font matching and renaming capabilities.

Moreover font metadata can be localized, a font file can contain translations for face names in various languages, that software can choose to use (or not). Reading the localized names contained in fonts is easier and more consistent across systems (but the font file metadata may be missing translations for some languages), always reading the English name (and displaying the translation of common face names using a single system-wide translation table) is more consistent as the system level (but the font file metadata may be missing an English version or use weird one-of-a-kind face names not present in the system-wide translation table).

And lastly some OpenType variants permit interpolating weight or slant, they don't use face names as such but numeric values on the various interpolation axis (variable fonts).

All of that means that "font name" is rather less simple, invariant and consistent that you may like it to be. Especially when crossing system borders.